ClassNotFoundException occurs with custom LoginModule in Open Liberty after migration
I am attempting to use a custom LoginModule (which implements LoginModule) in Open Liberty. This setup previously worked in WebSphere and JBoss environments, but after migrating to Open Liberty with updated frameworks, I encountered an issue.
Environment:

Open Liberty version: 24.0.0.6
JDK: RedHat OpenJDK 17
Jakarta EE: 10

What I did:
Created a jaas.config file with an entry like this example :

case1 {
com.sample.security.CustomLoginModule required;
　　};


Set the {server_name}/jvmoptions to specify the jaas.config path:

-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/liberty/config/jaas.config


Deployed the application and started it on Open Liberty.
*Note: *
I haven't made any specific JAAS configurations in the server.xml. The expectation is that the settings defined in the jaas.config file should be picked up automatically by Open Liberty.
The issue:

During the application's startup or while configuring JAAS, a ClassNotFoundException for my custom LoginModule is thrown in the console.log. This indicates that the custom module isn't being loaded correctly.

↓console.log

[2024/10/17 8:00:38:814 UTC] 00000018 m.ws.security.jaas.common.internal.JAASLoginModuleConfigImpl E CWWKS1141E: An unexpected exception occurred while executing class for name: com.sample.security.CustomLoginModule. Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sample.security.CustomLoginModule
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:751)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:327)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:705)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:584)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:553)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
at com.ibm.ws.security.jaas.common.internal.JAASLoginModuleConfigImpl.processDelegateOptions(JAASLoginModuleConfigImpl.java:251)
at com.ibm.ws.security.jaas.config.internal.JAASLoginConfigImpl.updateAppConfiguration(JAASLoginConfigImpl.java:194)
at com.ibm.ws.security.jaas.config.internal.JAASLoginConfigImpl.updateDelegateOptions(JAASLoginConfigImpl.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.security.jaas.config.internal.JAASLoginConfigImpl.getEntries(JAASLoginConfigImpl.java:150)
at com.ibm.ws.security.jaas.common.JAASConfigurationFactory.installJAASConfigurationFromJAASConfigFile(JAASConfigurationFactory.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.security.jaas.common.JAASConfigurationFactory.activate(JAASConfigurationFactory.java:86)



When I run a test case that uses the custom login module, Open Liberty logs an error indicating a missing delegate option.

Suspected causes and questions:

Incorrect placement of the custom LoginModule?

The classes are currently packaged within {server_name}/apps/hoge.ear. The jaas.config points to these classes. This setup worked in JBoss and WebSphere but seems to be causing issues in Open Liberty.

Is a delegate option required somewhere?

I suspect that I might need to set the delegate option for wsLoginModuleProxy, but I'm not sure where or how to configure it correctly.
Could anyone provide guidance or insights on why this might be happening and how to resolve it?

The delegate option is handle by the runtime code so you don't have to worry about this option. I am not sure what is the problem.
Can you enable Liberty trace with trace string com.ibm.ws.security.* and com.ibm.ws.classloading.*, recreate the problem and send me the trace.log and message.log.
Thank you.
